# Searching for a file with .java extension

Tags: java, file, search

is there any way that at first filter all files with the extension as "java" and then search for finding some files with that extension? can you explain with a snippet code?thanks

Comment: Wish this site was around when I was a student. 160 homework questions answered so far for "Johanna".

Comment: LOL... I had to read the book to finish my homework!

Comment: We can only hope the professors know about the site, too.  I guess this is why about 100% of the job seekers I interview are useless?

Comment: Contrary to that thought, students get the best answer possible (most of the times) which improves quality of learning as well.

Comment: That really depends on whether they're given the fish ready caught, filleted and cooked.

Comment: @murali - giving a student the right answer to a question does not help her learn to figure out the answer for herself.  Fortunately, homework cheats and rote-learners will eventually get caught out in a thorough job interview.  But not until after they've wasted thousands of dollars in college fees, etc, trying to buy their IT "meal ticket".

Answer (score 3):

I also vote for Apache Commons.

http://www.kodejava.org/examples/359.html gves a usage example:

```
package org.kodejava.example.commons.io;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class SearchFileRecursive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File root = new File("/home/foobar/Personal/Examples");

        try {
            String[] extensions = {"xml", "java", "dat"};
            boolean recursive = true;

            //
            // Finds files within a root directory and optionally its
            // subdirectories which match an array of extensions. When the
            // extensions is null all files will be returned.
            //
            // This method will returns matched file as java.io.File
            //
            Collection files = FileUtils.listFiles(root, extensions, recursive);

            for (Iterator iterator = files.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                File file = (File) iterator.next();
                System.out.println("File = " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to search all the memory, using this code? Instead of one directory? File root = new File("c:/"); doesn't actually work.

Answer (score 1):

On Unix you can try `find <dir> -name '*.java' -exec grep <search string> {} \;`

Comment: I suspect that her homework problem involves writing some Java code to do the work.

Comment: www.betterthangrep.com - 'ack' is a more powerful code search tool than the above. Recommended.

Comment: I use `grep <query> $( find <dir> -name *.java | xargs )`, which is worse if there's a LOT of java files, but slightly quicker to type when out-of-IDE

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this in Java, the easiest way is to use [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) and in particular [FileUtils.iterateFiles()](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#iterateFiles%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String[],%20boolean%29).

Having said that, if this is a homework question I doubt you'll get many marks for using the above. I suspect the purpose of the homework is to test your ability to write recursive routines (there's a clue there!) - not find 3rd party libraries (a valuable skill in itself, mind).

Answer (score 0):

This is made easy using FileSearcher.java found on [GitHub](https://github.com/ofekih/FileSearcher)

An example of finding all .java files in your whole computer would look like:

```
public class FindDotJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<File> dotJavaFiles = FileSearcher.findFiles(FileSearcher.SEARCH_EVERYTHING, "java");
    }
}
```

And you can just as easily only search the current folder or current folder + subfolders by changing SEARCH_EVERYTHING to CURRENT_FOLDER or SUBFOLDERS_AND_CURRENT.

I hope this helps!!!